# Exact location of E. coli in human body

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, ecoli, gastroenterology

E. coli lives in lower intestine. But exactly where can we find E. coli, and where is there none (or a really small amount) of it?
I need the exact names of parts of the lower intestine where we can find E. coli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Gastrointestinal Tract Location of Escherichia coli O157:H7 in Ruminants](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC127545/) (Grauke *et al.* 2002):

> in the lower GIT digesta, specifically the cecum, colon

It's about O157:H7, but I think the standard act a same.

Comment: FYI, this study was performed in sheep and cattle, so it may or may not apply to humans.

Comment: Yes I saw, not a human and not a standard E.Coli, but it's the best I found. If someone know better source, please share.

Comment: Best I could find for humans was [Population structure of gut Escherichia coli and its role in development of extra-intestinal infections](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3279776/) which says "large intestine"